# usage of stat() and std::remove() - TOCTOU issue

Tags: c++, race-condition

I have a following program in the form of:

```
stat(check_for_some_file) 
..... 
..... 
..... 
std::remove(remove the same file)
```

Two solutions that I could think of:

- one is again use stat() before I use std::remove()
- and another is, use some file descriptor to check if that file exists in place of stat()

Is there any better way to solve this issue?

Comment: It does not look like the standard library has an option for this, so the solution will be OS-dependent. What OS are you targeting?

Comment: Simplest solution is to proper error handling. Add `std::error_code&` argument for `std::filesystem::remove`.

Comment: @Botje I am targeting for linux

Comment: There is no way to know that a future call to `remove` will succeed. Even when that future is the next statement in your program. Even if it is a nanosecond away. The proper way to address the issue is to (1) make the call and (2) check the status of said call, in that order. Any calls to `stat` before `remove` are irrelevant.

Comment: What is TOCTOU and where do you mention it in your post?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews TOCTOU: [time of check to time of use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use). `stat` call is the check, `remove` call is the use.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with such a race condition is that the file can theoretically always be changed just between your stat check and the attempt to remove the file. It all depends on what you want to use `stat` for. If your concern is that you want to avoid errors from occurring if the removed file cannot be deleted then you can handle the errors, like so:

```cpp
std::error_code err_code;
if (std::filesystem::remove(fileName, err_code)) {
  // the file did exist and we succesfully removed it.
} else {
  // we attempted to remove the file but failed for some reason
  // the reason can be found in err code,it could be no_such_file_or_directory, permission_denied or something else.
}
```

However if you want to use stat to check something more complicated, for example to check the modification date then you are unlucky. As far as I know there is no way to only remove a file if it wasn't modified. If you want to have such behaviour you would need to coordinate a locking mechanism with whichever other program is changing the file.

If you do a rename, instead of a remove, you can check afterwards if the file was modified in the meantime, and you can try to put it back if that was the case. However, then there would still be the theoretical race condition of some other program accessing the file in the time that it had a different name.